# Are all these sentences trying to say the same thing but different ways?

Tags: sentence

> - むかし、フットボールはギリシャでもロームでも人気でした。
> - むかし、フットボールはギリシャでもロームでも人気がありました。
> - むかし、ギリシャとロームでフットボールが人気でした。

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the beautiful Italian capital, Japanese katakana would be written as ローマ (Roma).

Comment: Well, the sentences _roughly_ mean the same. If you have doubts, you need to clarify why you think they might be different.

Comment: For me, ローム is this: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0  (or, is it just me?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, the meaning is the same. I believe the thing that changes in these three cases is **focus**.

---

My understanding in detail, starting with **case 1**:

> The basic sentence is: フットボールは人気でした。
> Literary: `Football was popular`

Extra information about the location is then added.

> むかし、フットボールはギリシャで人気でした。
> Literary: `In the old days, football was popular in Greece`
> むかし、フットボールはロームでも人気でした。
> Literary: `In the old days, football was popular in Rome too.`

In one sentence this becomes:

> むかし、フットボールはギリシャでもロームでも人気でした。
> Literary: `In the old days, football was popular in Greece and in Rome too.`

The focus is on the *popularity* of the *locations*. `は` is an extra piece of information saying **what** was popular in `Greece and Rome`, but it can also be excluded. The sentence then becomes a simple:

> 人気でした。
> Literary: `It was popular.`

So `は` *loosely* adds an extra piece of information that could possibly be excluded, giving more focus on the adjective.

This is the exact opposite of **case 3** with `が`. In this case, choosing `が` allows us to emphasize on the sport and adding this piece of information with a more *"necessary"* feel to the sentence.

**Case 2** is a bit more interesting. If you were to try translating it word-by-word and take the *long way around*, you would end up with something like this:

`In the old days, as far as football is concerned, in Greece and in Rome too, there was popularity.`

This of course done to emphasize on this part: `there was popularity`. You can also add `to be found`, to the end of that to get a better understanding. It gives the hint that there is a bit more than the word itself states.
However, the most important difference is **formality** and **respect**. This way of saying it is a lot more formal and respectful.

These are my thoughts when reading these three sentences. I hope they are helpful to you, and hopefully answered your question.
*PS: Go Greece! <3 Haha :D*

Comment: I don’t see how the second sentence is more respectful than the first.

Comment: @aguijonazo I am indeed using “respect” a little liberally. But my understanding is that the more formal and structured your use of the language is, the more “respect” you show to the subject of the conversation.